# ASP.NET MVC dynamic paramaters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm trying to get a random amount of paramaters in my controller. I think code will explain my issue :-)

In my view I've something like:

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("Time" + (i-1)) %>
```

where `i` is a random value (for example 4).

So, in case `i` was indeed 4, my controller method woul look like:

```
public ActionResult Test(int Time0, Time1, Time2, Time3) {
  //some code
}
```

But, the problem is I don't now `i`. So, the controller should accept a random amount of params.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your checkboxes like this:

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("Time[" + i + "]") %>
```

Make sure `i` is sequential. That is, you cant have 1, 2, 3 and 5 (without 4). Actually you can have non-sequential indexes, but you would have to create another `input` for the index itself.

Your action should look like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int[] time)
{

}
```

Please refer to this link to read more about collection binding in ASP.NET MVC: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

Make your argument like: `int[] parameters`.

Comment: This won't work. The C# params keyword does not apply for ASP.NET MVC, at least not using the default model binder.

Comment: @AndréPena you are right. +1 for correcting me and your answer.